# How to decrypt a private key encryptet with the openssl ec command?

Tags: openssl

I have an encrypted key created like this:

```
openssl ecparam -genkey -name prime256v1 | openssl ec -aes-128-cbc -passout file:passphrase.txt -out out.key
```

This generates a key like so:

```
-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----\
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED\
DEK-Info: AES-128-CBC,88BFB9196A5A03B0206AA624EC55411F

4g025eMCoyW9ye/byEtTxMQxFO5ezl/LhCgjdGtIt2NdsE15kO1H9CONk5xskgMN
B6PK7ZpzwP9JcQZ+0p/sfNkd9zia70tP/c9jIjui9NbhM0WI7m75MJRVNPDv8Zzy
W2yLGWPFtQMF8cR3rW4iN/ycpI+QLtRo4/dbzhHqJ/E=\
-----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----
```

However, I am not able to decrypt it. Using the following command:

```
openssl enc -d -aes-128-cbc -pass file:passphrase.txt -in out.key -out decrypted.key
```

results in a *bad magic number*.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong command to decrypt the key. The "openssl enc" command is used to encrypt and decrypt arbitrary ciphertext.

To convert an encrypted ec key into a non-encrypted ec key you can instead do:

```
openssl ec -passin file:passphrase.txt -in encrypted.key -out decrypted.key
```

OR

```
openssl ec -passin pass:mypassword -in encrypted.key -out decrypted.key
```